# C# Confused on passing parameters with a string involved

Tags: c#, arrays, parameter-passing

Really confused on this homework assignment we have , I am not looking for the answer but some guidance. I am confused on how i would accept the user input and pass it through to pull one of these response from the array depending on their input being 1 through 5. Here is the problem below.

Create a program called Magic8Ball (console or GUI, your choice). The program should contain a method (written by you) that declares an array of at least five strings with Magic 8-Ball type phrases such as "The answer seems certain" (you can make up the phrases or use traditional ones--google magic 8ball phrases to see them. Your method should accept one parameter, an index into the array of phrase strings. Your method will display the phrase associated with the index that's passed into the method. For example, if the string at phrases[4] was "The future seems cloudy" and the calling program passed the value 4 into your method then the method would display "The future seems cloudy." Include error-handling in your method so that only valid indexes will produce output.

```
namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int response;

            string[] quotes;
            quotes = new string[5];

            {
                quotes[1] = ("Today is going to be a good day");
                quotes[2] = ("Tomorrow is going to rain");
                quotes[3] = ("Next month will be blissful");
                quotes[4] = ("You are very lucky to be here");
                quotes[5] = ("The love of your life notices you");
            };

            WriteLine("Please enter a number between one and five");

            response = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

            if (response = quotes[1])
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(quotes[response])`?

Comment: What does this have to do with parameter passing?

Comment: I am confused on how to take the users response and match it with one of the array strings and get the outcome. I am trying an if statement but i get an error.

Comment: This code will crash with an IndexOutOfRange exception when run, and it cannot be compiled until you fix the error in the if trying to assign a string to an integer variable

Comment: You guys are good... Steve you were right and it did crashed but i fixed that issue. This was a lot simpler than i thought. Thank you for the help.

Comment: But you fail one of your requirements. _Add error handling_ What if you type ABC instead of a number? What if you type 9 instead of a number between 1 and 5 (and we are back to the problem of IndexOutOfRange if you type 5)

Comment: @Steve The compiler went through with no errors even with me placing the 5.

Comment: @NoChance Thank you , still new to this site :)

Comment: @Steve is correct. Note that the compiler does not check this kind of error. This is an error that would occur at run-time. You should use the TryParse method. See: https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int response;

            string[] quotes = new string [5];


            {
                quotes[0] = ("Today is going to be a good day");
                quotes[1] = ("Tomorrow is going to rain");
                quotes[2] = ("Next month will be blissful");
                quotes[3] = ("You are very lucky to be here");
                quotes[4] = ("The love of your life notices you");
            }

            WriteLine("Please enter a number between one and five");

            response = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());


            WriteLine(quotes[response]);
```

Comment: This worked , thank you. Arrays have been confusing for me

Comment: Even if you are anwsering your own question, please add additional comments to it for others that might find this question usefull in any maner.

Comment: You need `WriteLine(quotes[response-1]);`

Answer (score 0):

`response` is a number from 1 to 5. To get the array item (string quote) that corresponds to the response you need to evaluate `quote[response-1]`. This is because arrays are 0-based in `C#`. That means an array of 5 items is indexed with `0..4`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] quotes = new string[]
        {
            "Today is going to be a good day",
            "Tomorrow is going to rain",
            "Next month will be blissful",
            "You are very lucky to be here",
            "The love of your life notices you"
        };

        int response;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out response);
        if (response>=1&&response<=quotes.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(quotes[response-1]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, the question has nothing to do with passing parameters.

Comment: I am trying to add the error handling link you did but it keeps telling me , " Use of unassigned variable"

Comment: What is the (quotes[response-1]) for ?

Comment: To implement error checking for input, use the `int.TryParse()` function. It assigns a value to `response` if the inpute can be converted to a number. Otherwise it makes `response=0`.

Comment: `quotes[response-1]` returns the element of the array the user decided. The user enter a number 1 to 5, and the element is selected by a number 0 to 4. See the comments in the begining of the code.